# Integrability of the derivative function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable funcion and A is a closed interval, it is not true that $f'$ is Riemann integrable in A. 
The question is:

•Is there a definiton of integral that makes $f'$ integrable in any case? (Maybe Lebesgue?)

•Could you provide some examples in wich integrability of $f'$ fails for different definitions of integral?

Thank you!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if $f'$ is bounded then it is Lebesgue integrable. With the Henstock-Kurzweil integral, $f(b)-f(a) = \displaystyle{\int_a^b} f'$ is always true (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral)

Answer (score 2):

For example, the function $$f(x) = \cases{0 & if $x=0$\cr x^2\cos(1/x^2) & if $x \ne 0$\cr}$$

is differentiable everywhere, but $f'$ is not Lebesgue integrable in a neighbourhood of $0$.